# Testcafe - How do I use document.querySelector for identical shadow doms?

Tags: typescript, testing, automation, automated-tests, testcafe

This question might come of as silly because of my lack of knowledge, but I'm struggling to understand how do I use document.querySelector for identical shadow doms.

Let's say we have 2 shadowDoms that are identical, visible at the same time and you can interact with both.

To perform clicks and what not using testcafe, I use something like:

```
private shadowDomSelector = Selector(() => document.querySelector('myShadowDom').shadowRoot) 
private myShadowDomElement = this.shadowDomSelector.find('input.flex-auto.rounded-full')

await t.typeText(this.myShadowDomElement, 'Test1')
```

This works, but how do I make the following work?:

```
private secondShadowDomSelector = Selector(() => document.querySelector('myShadowDom').shadowRoot)
private myShadowDomElement = this.secondShadowDomSelector.find('input.flex-auto.rounded-full')
```

I tried `private secondShadowDomSelector = Selector(() => document.querySelector('myShadowDom').shadowRoot).nth(1)`

or `private myShadowDomElement = this.ShadowDomSelector.find('input.flex-auto.rounded-full').nth(1)`

Please point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: How specifically is the second code block not working?

Comment: @Casey Rule I get an error: Expected false to be true, because I'm checking if the element is there on the 2nd shadow dom. I tried with other elements that are visible only on 1 shadow dom at a time (eg. a status, Active), that is not working either. So if I try something like: private statusCheck = this.secondShadowDomSelector.find('div.text-grey-inactive').withText('Active') / await t.expect(this.statusCheck.visible).ok({timeout: 10000}) it doesn't work.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, the only difference between these two code blocks are the variable names.  Can you provide more context for where these pieces of code are coming from?